# Copy text in Firefox reducing number of spaces to one

Tags: css, firefox, clipboard, spaces

I have problem with copy function in firefox.

For example i will use this simple code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style='white-space: pre-wrap;'>123456     789123</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As result i will get text with 5 spaces, because of using *pre-wrap* style, which is correct.
Problem is, when i copy this text in firefox (ctrl + c or right click -> copy) and then i paste it (to browser, notepad...) there is only one space in result, not 5 of them.

In other browser it works correctly.

Does anyone of you had this problem?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: there is already a bug reported https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116083

Comment: As a workaround, change the `div` to a `pre`; that will work. By the way, the bug @4dgaurav mentioned was filed in 2001, so I wouldn't count on a solution any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Unfortunately i can not always use `pre` tag, because for example if it is used inside `a href` tag, in IE8 after right click on link i have no option for opening in new window. Thats why i have used `white-space` style for now.
Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: Why not to use &nbsp;?

Comment: @AlexanderDayan Nonbreaking spaces won't copy as spaces (they're different characters).

Comment: It also removes new lines.